# Chernoff Bound as an approximation for binomial distribution tightness.

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, approximation, binomial-distribution, distribution-tails

I'm curious about how well the Chernoff bound approximates the value of the upper tail of a binomial distribution.

It is well known that, for $X\sim B(n,p),\ \delta >0$:

$$P(X \geq (1+\delta)np) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{\delta^2np}{2+\delta}\right)$$

What, if anything, can be said about how closely this upper bound approximates the probability on the left hand side? That is, how does the following function vary with $n,p$:

$$f(n,p)=\lvert{P(X \geq (1+\delta)np) - \exp\left(-\frac{\delta^2np}{2+\delta}\right)}\rvert$$

For concreteness, let's take $\delta = \frac{n+1}{2np} - 1$ with $p<0.5$, so that this is really a question about:

$$f(n,p)=\lvert{P(X \geq (n+1)/2) - \exp\left(-\frac{((1-2p)n+1)^2}{2((1+2p)n+1)}\right)}\rvert$$

Plugging a few test cases in, for small $n$, I found that these two quantities can differ by orders of magnitude. But a more complete picture eludes me, as well as the regime in terms of $n,p$ where the Chernoff bound is actually a good approximation to the Binomial tail. Any suggestions very welcome!

I've reposted this here as  I suspect it will get a better response in math.se. I hope that is within the rules.

EDIT: From plotting, it seems that for small (odd) values of $n$ and restricting $0.05 <p < 0.4$, we can construct a modified approximation that bounds the below function $|g|<0.1$:

$$g(n,p)={{P(X \geq (n+1)/2) - \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\exp\left(-\frac{((1-2p)n+1)^2}{2((1+2p)n+1)}\right)}}$$

Curious now whether this is provable? Any light on this would be of great interest.

Comment: I don't have a good answer to your exact question, but I can give a little bit of direction. For large $n$ Cramer's theorem gives the "best possible" approximation of this type in some sense, but it doesn't pretend to be a bound in either direction. You could compare the Chernoff bound to the Cramer's theorem approximation and examine how they differ.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the suggestion, looking into Cramer's is certainly something I haven't yet tried. It is however relatively clear that the bound is tightest for large $n$, so I suppose my interest is more for small $n<50$.

What I have observed from a few plots is suppressing the Chernoff bound with a $1/\sqrt{n}$ factor appears to give a better closeness for small values of n. How to prove this mathematically, is unclear to me however.

Comment: For small enough $n$ the tail is dominated by the first possibility. Consider for instance $n=10$ and $X \geq 8$. The probabilities you're looking at are now $45p^8 q^2,10 p^9 q$ and $p^{10}$. Even for $p=1/2$, you see that 80% of that tail is just the first term, and it gets more dramatic for $p<1/2$. Unfortunately there's an intermediate regime where probably neither this nor a Chernoff-type bound will be very good.

Comment: @Ian I agree, if we take the extreme end of the tail, the latter terms fall off towards zero so will naturally align well with the decaying exponential. It's as soon as we consider $X\geq 6$, say, where $X=6,7$ are included in the sum, where we discover the departure (as the exponential is far larger than the corresponding probabilities).

Comment: I believe the $g(n,p)$ in my edit is very close to zero for $p$ not too close to $0.5$ and $n$ not too small (say, below 8, at which stage, the probability itself can be calculated with relatively little effort anyway without the need for approximation). Chernoff works very well for very large $n$, so it's a function that bounds the intermediate $n$s that is of interest. As you quite correctly point out, this is where Chernoff seems to fail as a good approximation.